# Pattern.compile() from cached string vs Caching the compiled pattern

Tags: java, regex, caching, infinispan

I've a set of patterns that I match every request to determine what to do. The number of patterns is ~60 now but it will soon grow to more than a 1000.

I get the patterns from the database and I use infinispan to cache my patterns.

`Pattern.compile()` is really fast and I'm not sure if I should cache the compile pattern or the string. `Pattern` seems to be `Serializable`. Is there any issue with caching `Pattern` objects?

#### Edit

I'm using a remote infinispan. It is a distributed cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any issue with caching Pattern objects?

You can do both, either cache the pattern string or the `Pattern` object. I recommend caching the pattern string in the distributed cache.

Looking in the internals of the `Pattern` object you will see that actually only the original pattern string is serialized. That means, when deserialized (aka fetched from the distributed cache) the `Pattern` instance needs to build the internal parse tree again.

With caching the pattern string, you will have two advantages: When you inspect the cache contents its readable instead of binary. In the serialized form you store more data then you need, because the serialized stream would contain the types. So I expect a tiny advantage because the serialization overhead is not there.

If your patterns are complex, building the object tree again is more costly. To get around this, you need an in-process cache which caches the actual object reference. You can combine these with the distributed cache. A modern in-process cache with fastest access time would be Caffeine or [cache2k](https://cache2k.org). How much time you can save, depends on your overall scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Instances of this class are immutable and are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.

So, by all means compile them once and reuse them.

> Pattern.compile() is really fast

It's quite fast, but not running it unnecessarily is faster.

Comment: But I'm fetching it from a distributed cache?